# Something proved "sound" ultimately, not beneficial... in line with my skills and goals. Is there a word for this?

Tags: single-word-requests

> Although my path to radiology has been somewhat untraditional — I made the transition to nuclear medicine after transferring from radiology and, prior to that, training briefly in ophthalmology — my career decisions proved "*enlightening*" *ultimately*.

I am trying to make the point that my decision proved *"sound"* *ultimately* or *"correct for me" ultimately* or *"in line with my eventual interests, skills etc."*

I just seem unable to come up with the nuanced word for this sentence.

Comment: "Satisfying", perhaps? As in "my career path has been unconventional but satisfying".

Comment: It's not clear from the text, so I can't be sure, but it seems to me when you made your earlier decisions you *weren't* trying to improve your chances of ending up in radiology. So it seems a bit odd to me to characterize those decisions as "good, sound" (they just *happened* to be "compatible" with your later-recognized goal). I might just say your earlier choices were ***fortuitous*** (you didn't know what you were doing, or why, but it all worked out in the end). But you need to explain in more detail exactly what you want to say here.

Comment: Stealing @FumbleFingers word "fortuitous", maybe this? ***Although my path to radiology was not very traditional — some brief training in ophthalmology followed by nuclear medicine, after which I transitioned to radiology — my career decisions proved to be fortuitous.*** (Might want to omit "to be" at the end, I don't know.)

Comment: If your readers are mathematically inclined, **converged** would work.

Comment: "matching career" = career matching one's skill-set

Comment: "suited to me" or "it suited me better"? "a better fit for me"?

Comment: '... worked out well'.

Answer (score 1):

You could say, "...my career decisions have ultimately proven suitable to my interests."

You could also use "fitting", "appropriate", or "reflective of"

Answer (score 0):

Possibly "congruous"? As in, "My career path, though non-traditional, ultimately was congruous with my ideology (needs, etc.).
Or, as you nearly said, "aligned with" my needs.